# GitHub issue creation API

Tags: bash, curl, github

I'm trying to create an issue with a GitHub repository:

```
curl -d '{"title":"my-new-repo","body":"my new issue description"}' https://api.github.com/repos/np98765/BattleKits/issues
```

This just returns:

```
{
  "message": "Not Found"
}
```

I'm authenticating like this:

```
curl -u "user:password" https://api.github.com
```

What am I doing wrong?
http://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#create-an-issue

Comment: Same problem here. Did you find the cause?

Answer (score 2):

You don't seem to call `POST` in your `curl` request.

You could at least try (following "[REST-esting with cURL](http://blogs.plexibus.com/2009/01/15/rest-esting-with-curl/)"):

```
curl -X POST -i -d '{"title":"my-new-repo","body":"my new issue description"}' https://api.github.com/repos/np98765/BattleKits/issues
```

With `-i` for having a look at the response headers.

Comment: curl should always use POST when `-d` is used.

Comment: @surendar maybe the API has changed? My answer seems to still be compliant with http://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#create-an-issue though.

Answer (score 1):

Just tried `curl -u "$REPORTER":"$TOKEN" https://api.github.com/repos/$OWNER/$REPO/issues -d @$JSON_WITH_ISSUE` and it worked.

This uses token authentication and reporter is my user, while owner of the repo is the user to whom I'm reporting the issue.